# How to make my compiler show result with space?

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I use Android Studio as a Java compiler where I work with a Java class.

My compiler run the code in one line like this:

```
levels9mark
```

but I want result shown in multiple lines:

```
levels
9
mark
```

I check the setting and I enable show white space but it did not work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the compiler but all with your program. How do you write this text?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the printing line.

this is the wrong line:

> System.out.print**f**("");

this is the right one.

> System.out.print**ln**("");